# timezone issue in magento 2.4.4p1

Tags: magento2, timezone, datetime

When I apply a purchased date filter to the customer order grid page continuously loads and  in the log, I am getting the below error

After Upgrade php7.4 to php8 version issue is happening.

> 2023-01-10T06:48:08.614459+00:00] main.CRITICAL:
> Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The DateTime object
> timezone needs to be the same as the "America/Chicago" timezone in
> config. in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php:345

check config PFA

[image]

Grid

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue I fixed this by overriding the below file and adding a condition. it's worked for me.

> di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection" type="Custom\Module\Preference\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection" />
```

> Collection.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Preference\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends SearchResult
{
   
    private $timeZone;

  
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = Order::class,
        TimezoneInterface $timeZone = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
        $this->timeZone = $timeZone ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(TimezoneInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
        foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
            $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . $columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        if ($field === 'created_at') {
            if (is_array($condition)) {
                    foreach ($condition as $key => $value) {
                    //new if condition added to resolve timezone issue
                    if(!is_object($value) && (strpos($value, '/') !== false)){
                            $condition[$key] = $this->timeZone->convertConfigTimeToUtc($value);
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }
}
```